# How to deserialize JSON data using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, system.text.json

This time I am needing some help deserializing some data that comes from a Web API using using System.Text.Json. After searching all over the place I had found nothing that can really help me solving this issue

Here is a sample of the data:

For the UF Indicator:

```
{
    "UFs": [
        {
            "Valor": "30.008,40",
            "Fecha": "2021-09-10"
        }
    ]
}
```

For USD Indicator:

```
{
    "Dolares": [
        {
            "Valor": "791,28",
            "Fecha": "2021-09-10"
        }
    ]
}
```

For UTM Indicator:

```
{
"UTMs": [
        {
            "Valor": "52.631",
            "Fecha": "2021-09-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

And a sample for USD with multiple sets of data:

```
{
"Dolares": [
    {
        "Valor": "767,10",
        "Fecha": "2021-09-02"
    },
    {
        "Valor": "768,36",
        "Fecha": "2021-09-03"
    },
    {
        "Valor": "766,53",
        "Fecha": "2021-09-06"
    },
    {
        "Valor": "770,33",
        "Fecha": "2021-09-07"
    },
    {
        "Valor": "777,94",
        "Fecha": "2021-09-08"
    },
    {
        "Valor": "787,51",
        "Fecha": "2021-09-09"
    },
    {
        "Valor": "791,28",
        "Fecha": "2021-09-10"
    }
]
}
```

This is the class I need to Deserialize to:

```
public class Indicador : IIndicador
{
    public string Valor { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
}
```

The issue starts when I try to Deserialize using this:

```
var dataFromApi = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var indicador = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Indicador>(dataFromApi);
```

I also tried using this "solution" but with no luck at all:

```
var dataFromApi = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var indicador = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,List<indicador>>>(dataFromApi);
```

So far the only solution has been to create a "container" class that can help me handle that odd "UFs" as a list, since this WebAPI can return multiple other economics indicators than "UFs" which can change to a lot of other concepts, is there a way to map what ever comes from the WebAPI to my generic Indicador class?, the idea is to use a simple object when there is just 1 data and an IEnumerable when there are more than one. I need to stop the dependency for each type of indicator available.

Comment: Try `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,List<iIndicador>>>(dataFromApi)`

Comment: Sorry… my code had an issue i corrected thanks to your comment. Tried that also with no luck at all, it just shows me the dictionary is null on debug.

Comment: You have a parent object with UFs property that have an array of your object...
Try to create a parent object and deserialize that..

Comment: you can have a Parent object for UFs or you use the KeyPairValue for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Concerns / Areas of Improvement

Your final paragraph is a little vague and you don't have anymore examples. As such the answer might not be quite as specific as you are looking for.

> multiple other economics indicators than "UFs"

Would be nice to see some other examples.

> map what ever comes from the WebAPI to my generic Indicador class

Potentially possible, but it remains to be seen how the other data is structured.

## Simplest Example

I think you are missing this part of the deserialization process

```
List<Indicador> indicadors = dataDict["UFs"]; // <-- Will fail If "UFs" is not present
```

Below is a top level C# program to how to deserialize the given data to a `List<Indicador>`.

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// test data
string dataFromApi = @"{
    ""UFs"": [
        {
            ""Valor"": ""30.008,40"",
            ""Fecha"": ""2021-09-10""
        },
        {
            ""Valor"": ""40.008,50"",
            ""Fecha"": ""2021-10-10""
        }
    ]
}";

var dataDict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<Indicador>>>(dataFromApi);
List<Indicador> indicadors = dataDict["UFs"]; // <-- Will fail If "UFs" is not present 

// print out the indicadors
indicadors.ForEach(indicador => Console.WriteLine(indicador));

// Using records because they are brief and come with a good default ToString() method
// You can use regular class if you require
public abstract record IIndicador(string Valor, string Fecha);
public record Indicador(string Valor, string Fecha): IIndicador(Valor, Fecha);
```

The output of the above top level C# program

```
Indicador { Valor = 30.008,40, Fecha = 2021-09-10 }
Indicador { Valor = 40.008,50, Fecha = 2021-10-10 }
```

If "UFs" key is not guaranteed then you can use one of the Dictionary methods to determine if the key is present. For example

```
if (dataDict.ContainsKey("UFs")) ...
```

## Speculation

Going out on a limb here trying to address some of the aspects of your last paragraph. (You will need to clarify if this address all your concerns and adapt to meet your needs) `System.Text.Json` also has `JsonConverterFactory` and `JsonConverter<T>` for more advanced Conversion requirements should you need them.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// test data
string multiDataFromApi = @"{
    ""UFs"": [
        {
            ""Valor"": ""30.008,40"",
            ""Fecha"": ""2021-09-10""
        },
        {
            ""Valor"": ""40.008,50"",
            ""Fecha"": ""2021-10-10""
        }
    ],
    ""UFOs"": [
        {
            ""Valor"": ""30.008,40"",
            ""Fecha"": ""2021-09-10""
        }
    ]
}";

string singleDataFromApi = @"{
    ""UFs"": [
        {
            ""Valor"": ""30.008,40"",
            ""Fecha"": ""2021-09-10""
        },
        {
            ""Valor"": ""40.008,50"",
            ""Fecha"": ""2021-10-10""
        }
    ]
}";

processDataFromApi(multiDataFromApi);
processDataFromApi(singleDataFromApi);

void processDataFromApi(string json)
{
    var dataDict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<Indicador>>>(json);

    if (dataDict.Count == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-- Single Key Processing --");
        List<Indicador> indicadors = dataDict.Values.First();
        indicadors.ForEach(indicador => Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", indicador));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-- Multi Key Processing --");
        foreach (var keyValuePair in dataDict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing Key: {keyValuePair.Key}");
            List<Indicador> indicadors = keyValuePair.Value;
            indicadors.ForEach(indicador => Console.WriteLine("\t{0}",indicador));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
}

// Using records because they are brief and come with a good default ToString() method
// You can use regular class if you require
public abstract record IIndicador(string Valor, string Fecha);
public record Indicador(string Valor, string Fecha): IIndicador(Valor, Fecha);
```

which will produce the following output

```
-- Multi Key Processing --
Processing Key: UFs
        Indicador { Valor = 30.008,40, Fecha = 2021-09-10 }
        Indicador { Valor = 40.008,50, Fecha = 2021-10-10 }
Processing Key: UFOs
        Indicador { Valor = 30.008,40, Fecha = 2021-09-10 }
-----------------------------
-- Single Key Processing --
        Indicador { Valor = 30.008,40, Fecha = 2021-09-10 }
        Indicador { Valor = 40.008,50, Fecha = 2021-10-10 }
-----------------------------
```

Comment: My dude! worked like a charm!, since you asked for some extra data sample.. let me explain, here in Chile we have several economics indicators like UF, USD , UTM and others, so i will correct the original post so it can include more sample data.